# Groups where discrete logarithm is hard

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, elliptic-curves, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

What are examples of groups, where DLP (discrete logarithm problem) is hard?

Two obvious ones are: integers modulo $p$ ($p$ being prime) and elliptic curves over finite fields. What are the others?

Comment: Relevant: RSA Labs says "The best discrete logarithm algorithms [over finite fields] have expected running times similar to those of the best factoring algorithms." ([link](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2193))

Comment: As a point of clarification, you should distinguish between $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})^ \times$. DLP is hard in the latter, and trivial in the former.

Comment: The difficulty of the discrete logarithm problem in a group is not a property of a group (that is, it is not invariant under isomorphism of groups); it is a property of a specific algorithm computing the group law using a specific algorithmic representation of the group's elements.

Comment: [Binary extension fields are no longer hard](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83336/18298)

Answer (score 2):

As you probably already know, you can take [discrete logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) for any cyclic group. However as you can see on the linked wiki page, no algorithm is known for computing general discrete logarithms.

However some other [popular choices](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/wiki/index.php/Discrete_Logarithms) of groups that are used for discrete logarithm are the algebraic torus over finite fields and the divisor class group of a curve over a finite field.